# Unobtrusive Validation not validating one field on form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

So I have a list of fields being created by razor but the field `PhoneNumber` is not being validated. The weird thing is that if I put the fields outsidee of the first if statement the validation will work fine. On top of that both of the other fields validate fine aswell, it's just `PhoneNumber`

```
@if (Model?.CompanyContactList != null)
{
    if (Model.CompanyContactList.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.CompanyContactList.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @Html.EditorFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.EditorFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].Email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CompanyContactList[i].Email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel for PhoneNumber

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\+?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{6,12}$", ErrorMessage = "This must be a vaild phone number")]
[MaxLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your Phone number must be less than 15 numbers")]
[Display(Name = "Phone Number Mobile")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

The field rendered in HTML

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
data-val-maxlength="Your Phone number must be less than 15 numbers" data-val-maxlength-max="16" 
data-val-phone="The Phone Number Mobile field is not a valid phone 
number." data-val-regex="This must be a vaild phone number" data-val-regex-
pattern="^\+?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{6,12}$" id="CompanyContactList_0__PhoneNumber" 
name="CompanyContactList[0].PhoneNumber" type="tel" value="22222222222">

<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" 
data-valmsg-for="CompanyContactList[0].PhoneNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

JS files referenced ( in the head of the page)

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas why this one field wont validate?

Comment: What is the point of the `if` statement (its not required)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke for displaying data to the user to edit, `if` to check if the list is not empty

Comment: Also show the rendered JavaScript for the call to the `.validate()` method.

Comment: It not needed at all - if the collection is empty, then the `for` loop will not be executed. And try removing the `[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]`

Comment: @Sparky It is inside a `form` so I don't have js to call `.validate()` since Jquery validate hooks onto the submit function of the form (as far as I understand)

Comment: Correct.  Thanks to the unobtrusive validation plugin, `.validate()` is generated and called automatically, and the rules are defined as per the HTML attributes.  Since the field validates fine when it's generated outside of the `if` statement, this issue is confined to ASP and/or Unobtrusive Validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just tried it by removing both and just single `if` statements and both times it errored out because it is calling `Model.CompanyContactList.Count` which is a `null reference` when the collection is empty. That aside, also tried it with removing `[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]` but no change

Comment: @Toxicable, You have already checked for `null` with the first `if` block. The 2nd `if` block (checking `.Count` is pointless)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, my bad, added a constructor to the ViewModel to make an empty list rather than null, therefore got rid of both `if` statements however still did not solve the validation issue

Comment: You have already said _if I put the fields outside of the first if statement the validation will work fine_! And it all looks fine. What are you entering and what validation message are you expecting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I did, now it's not working anywhere, other fields on the page with the exact same data annotations work though ( they are not in loops or `if` statements). I am entering either nothing or letters to get the expected error "Required" or  "Invaild Phone Number" from the Regex evalutaion

Comment: Loops have nothing to do with it. And you have a `[Phone]` attribute which is a regex validation, but you have also added another regex validation meaning a potential conflict. Try removing one or the other.

Comment: And it works fine for me - refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkI1qQ)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah I know `[Phone]` has it's own regex but it didn't appear to be working very well, either way I removed it and still having the same problem

Comment: Note also, you do not have a `[Required]` attribute, so entering nothing will not be a validation error (because its **not**  required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the help, still havn't fixed it but I have almost exactly what you have, there must be something else i've done on the page that's messing with it

Comment: Check, if the regular expression you are using is correct. You can test it here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Toxicable, Can you change the @Html.EditorFor() to a @Html.TextboxFor() for the phone number and try again?

Comment: @TejSoft Just tried it with the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` with no change, also the Regex is working as expected